# Site not showing correct PHP version

Tags: php, ubuntu

I'm running Ubuntu 22.04 which shows PHP8.2 as the latest version installed. However, my site is reflecting that I'm still running 8.0. I tried uploading a phpinfo.php file to confirm that and it indeed says I'm still running 8.0. I've tried running `a2enmod php8.2` and the console shows that it's enabled. Not sure what to do here. Do I have to purge the old PHP packages in order for the new one to become default? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you restart your webserver? `sudo systemctl restart apache2`

Comment: @mark_b Yes I did

Comment: Did you check the `SetHandler ` PHP version in .conf file for your domain config, location should be `/etc/apache2/sites-available/YOURDOMAIN.conf`

Comment: @PragneshChauhan I don't have a YOURDOMAIN.conf in that location. All I have is 000-default.conf, 000-default.conf.dpkg-dist, and default-ssl.conf